How would I know if a method is callable when it's defined on composite interfaces
I've noticed I don't have any way to check if calling a method might cause my program to panic.
package main

type MyInterface interface {
    MyMethod()
}

type MyType1 struct {
    MyInterface
}

type MyType2 struct {
    MyInterface
}

func (mt MyType1) MyMethod() {
    println("MyType1.MyMethod called")
}

func main() {
    var myInstance MyInterface

    var mt1 MyType1
    myInstance = mt1
    if myInstance.MyMethod != nil {
        // this definitely works
        myInstance.MyMethod()
    }

    var mt2 MyType2
    myInstance = mt2

    //None of the following works to check if MyMethod is nil

    //if myInstance.MyMethod != nil {
    if _, ok := myInstance.(MyInterface); ok {
        // MyMethod is not nil, but this will panic
        myInstance.MyMethod()
        // How would I know that calling MyMethod cause panic?
    }
}

Do I have a way to actually know if I can call MyMethod() or not?
I tried checking the three mentioned ways to check if I can call, seems like it's not possible.

A method of an interface can never be nil. The interface itself can be nil.

A method of an interface cannot be nil but the interface may be nil, and when you call a method of a nil interface, the program will panic.
In you example, myInstance is an interface and its value is mt2. mt2 is a struct containing an interface variable, but that interface variable is never initialized, so it is nil, that is: mt2.MyInterface==nil is true. Thus, when you call a method it panics, not because the method is nil, but the interface you're using to call that method is nil. To solve, you need to initialize that struct field, using something like:
mt2.MyInterface=mt1

In the declaration:
type MyType2 struct {
    MyInterface
}

what you are doing is embedding an interface field to the struct. The struct actually has a field called MyInterface, and since it is embedded, it inherits the methods of that interface.
